# Get end coordinates of textview

Tags: android, textview, ratingbar

I want to get end coordinates of textview inside frame layout and then add rating bar at the end of text. I tried textview.getright() and textview.getbottom() but it gives me 0 value. Please help.[check this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o27TO.png)
this is what i want to achieve [image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI1SK.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

```
int w = image.getWidth();//x
int h = image.getHeight();//y
```

you can find point using x,y;

the starting point would be always 0

Comment: i want to show (append) rating bar at the end of last character of the textview.

Comment: that just place the drawable to the right side not at the end of text ( last character of string ) and second thing , it needs more than 10 different drawable ( for rating star , because its not static , changes based on server response).